# <jsp:forward page=""> shows blank page

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to Java Programming and I am trying to do a  in my control page, but the  page is blank.  Please help.

Codes for calling page is as follows:

```
if(strClashInd == "Y") {
  out.println("clash records detected!");    
%> 
  <jsp:forward page="displayClash.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="eventRsv" value="paramValue" />
  </jsp:forward>
<%
} else {
  out.println("proceed with bookings!");
}
```

Comment: which `out.println()` message prints on console 1st or 2nd ?

Comment: `if(strClashInd == "Y")`.. use `strClashInd.equals("Y")` !

Comment: Please don't pollute the JSP with scriptlets ...

Comment: Hi, nothing is printed on console.

Answer (score 2):

The way that you are comparing Strings is wrong

```
if(strClashInd == "Y")
```

whether this java code is in jsp or a POJO

use `String.equals` or even better in jsp use `<c:if ....>`

Comment: I realised.  Thanks for alerting!

Comment: but it isn't the answer to the problem I was facing.

Comment: so what is the question then?

Comment: even after changing to if(strClashInd.equals("Y")), when it comes to the forward code, it shows a blank page.  I am not sure if I have gotten to the root of the problem but I think it has something to do with the output buffer issue.